# Is there any way user can set timezone from (database) their profile setting in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, timezone, codeigniter-3

I am working on user setting page where some of the default settings for the user are like user default timezone, user date format, user time format.

I am able to store user-specific setting in my database and get them. but when the user changes his timezone it's set properly but it does not show date according to latest timezone.

For example, user current timezone is 'Asia/Kolkata' and when he update timezone to any other timezone like 'America/New_York' the details get saved in the database and it also shows current timezone 'America/New_York' but it does not reflect 'America/New_York' date and time. its shows 'Asia/Kolkata' time only. When I re-login the same user its shows correct time as per last updated timezone.

I have already tried below code

```php
$utc_time = $dateinfo; // date from database
$timezone = $ci->session->userdata('user_settings')->TIME_ZONE; // user last updated timezone
$date_obj = new DateTime($utc_time, new DateTimeZone($ci->session->userdata('user_settings')->TIME_ZONE));
$date_obj->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));
$display_date = $date_obj->format(get_datetimeformat() . '(e)');

return $display_date; // show date based on updated timezone
```

I am expecting to show date and time based on selected timezone without re-login.

If anyone can help me in the right direction, it will very helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In your **Controller** do this

```
  $user_timezone = 'Asia/Tokyo'; //make sure you get this data from your user
  date_default_timezone_set($user_timezone); //set it as default according to their time zone.

   echo $user_timezone. "<br>";
   echo date('Y-m-d');
   echo "<br>The time is " . date("h:i:sa");
```

Let me know the result.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: This is just reflecting for the current date and time. If I have date-time stored in database then its not changing based on timezone.

Comment: @SurendraSoni it's not reflecting. make sure you get the timezone from your database and pass it to this variable $user_timezone.

Comment: I am taking value from database only. but its was showing the same. The issue was I was not storing date and time details in database in UTC format. I have resolved this issue by changing function from date() to gmdate() function for storing data. Please refer my given answer below. Thanks for your help. I really Appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all response. I have solved the issue.

I have converted all date() function to gmdate() in my application so now all date and time get store in UTC in my database.

I did some changes in my helper function as below, and its working like charm for me.

```
$date_obj = new DateTime($utc_time, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

Thanks!!!